# structure of data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I want to start using Firebase.

I will start with a simple database for comics.

Which structure is the best?

Remark Structure 1: how can I get a list of series?

Remark Structure 2: too close to sql databases?

STRUCTURE 1:

```
{
  "comics" : {
    "1" : {
      "serie" : "Batman",
      "nr" : "1",
      "title" : "Title of issue 1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "serie" : "Batman",
      "nr" : "2",
      "title" : "Title of issue 2"
    },
    "3" : {
      "serie" : "Spiderman",
      "nr" : "1",
      "title" : "Title of issue 1"
    }
  }
}
```

STRUCTURE 2:

```
{
  "issues" : {
    "1" : {
      "serie" : "1",
      "nr" : "1",
      "title" : "Title of issue 1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "serie" : "1",
      "nr" : "2",
      "title" : "Title of issue 2"
    },
    "3" : {
      "serie" : "2",
      "nr" : "1",
      "title" : "Title of issue 1"
    }
  },
  "series" : {
    "1" : {
      "title" : "Batman"
    },
    "2" : {
      "serie" : "Spiderman"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither. Arrays are inflexible in Firebase so please don't use them. Node names should be created with childByAutoId. Also, the structure you use is determined by what you want to get out of the database; relationships, denormalized data, queries etc so there's no way to answer the question without that info,

Comment: I want to get the list of series, when you click on a serie you see the list of issues of that serie.

Comment: so even for a simple database (example list of movies) you don't use an integer as key, but something generated by childByAutoId?

Comment: In Firebase (as in most NoSQL databases) you should model your data for how your app consumes it. For good introductions, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) or watch the [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would first take a look at [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) in the docs.
- Then as per Jay's advice, allow firebase to generate unique keys for your records.
- Keep a record of each `series`, and as a child, you can keep a list
  of its associated episodes.
- Keep a record of each `episode`, and here you can keep more details
  about it (year, cast, rating, etc). You can even track the id of the series it belongs to if you need to.

Your data structure might look something like this:

```js
{
  "series": {
    "58371074b694fc9c35ec8891": {
      "name": "Batman",
      "episodes": {
        "583710741ffbf07cfccf7ba2": true,
        "58371074539dde71b245d5a1": true,
        "583710744b14fd3a654a6d75": true
      }
    },
    "58371074898bed03d73cd12c": {
      "name": "Spiderman",
      "episodes": {
        "58371074b63304e2617b558e": true
      }
    }
  },
  "episode": {
    "583710741ffbf07cfccf7ba2": {
      "name": "Batman Begins"
    },
    "58371074539dde71b245d5a1": {
      "name": "Batman Returns"
    },
    "583710744b14fd3a654a6d75": {
      "name": "Batman Forever"
    },
    "58371074b63304e2617b558e": {
      "name": "The Amazing Spider-Man"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: obviously the keys in the above example have not been generated by firebase, but you get the idea of how your data structure might look.